# How to add the possibility of multi curl requests to the general method of sending curl?

Tags: php, curl

How to add the possibility of multi curl requests to the general method of sending cURL (curl_init | curl_multi_init), or rather rewrite it to multi curl, because when sending one url, it will work as usual.

Here is my existing method of sending cURL (it needs to be modified to multi curl)

```
// A common method for sending requests via curl

    private function request($type, $url, $data = [], $headers = [], $curlopts = [])
    {
        $default_headers = [
            'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, lzma',
            'Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1',
            'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/42.0.2393.517'
        ];

        $default_curlopts = [
            //CURLOPT_INTERFACE => '46.254.16.170',
            CURLOPT_URL => (strpos($url, 'https://') === 0 ? '' : 'https://site.ru') . $url . ($type == 'GET' && count($data) > 0 ? '?' . http_build_query($data) : ''),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array_merge($default_headers, $headers),
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip',
            CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $this->auth_cookie_file,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $this->auth_cookie_file,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
        ];

        if ($type == 'POST') {
            $default_curlopts[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
            $default_curlopts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = http_build_query($data);
        }

        curl_setopt_array($this->ch, array_replace($default_curlopts, $curlopts));

        sleep($this->sleep_time);
        $response = (string)curl_exec($this->ch);

        $result = [
            'http_code' => curl_getinfo($this->ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE),
            'raw_response' => $response,
            'header_size' => curl_getinfo($this->ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)
        ];

        $result['header'] = mb_substr($response, 0, $result['header_size'], 'UTF-8');
        $result['headers'] = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode("\n", $result['header'])));
        $result['body'] = mb_substr($response, $result['header_size'], null, 'UTF-8');

        return $result;
    }
```

This is my multi curl

```
// Todas url gravadas em array
$urls = [
"https://site.ru",
"https://site2.ru"
];

// Setando opção padrão para todas url e adicionando a fila para processamento
$mh = curl_multi_init();

foreach($urls as $key => $url) {
$ch[$key] = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$key]);
}

// Executando consulta
do {
  curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  curl_multi_select($mh);
} while ($running > 0);

// Obtendo dados de todas as consultas e retirando da fila
foreach(array_keys($ch) as $key){

                $content = curl_multi_getcontent($ch[$key]);

                $results[$key] = $content;
 
                curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[$key]);

}

// Finalizando
curl_multi_close($mh);

var_dump($content);
```

I tried to refine the method myself, but I didn't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: you shouldn't select() if $running is zero, it would be faster to ```for(;;){  curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);if($running<1){break;}curl_multi_select($mh);}```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: I need to change the first script - the existing method of sending cURL. But the optimization of the second will not hurt. Thanks.